# Smart Array E200i battery on ML350 G5 did not fix the warning message (battery failure)

Tags: hp-proliant, hp-smart-array

I have got this warning message on the System Management in a Proliant server ML350 G5.

```
Degraded Accelerator
Name    Value
Status: Temporarily Disabled
Error Code: Cache Disabled Low Batteries
Serial Number:  P9A3A0B9SX5023
Total Memory:   131072 KB
Read Cache: 50%
Write Cache:    50%
Battery Status: Failed
Read Errors:    0
Write Errors:   0
```

I order a new battery HP part number: 307132-001 (used battery but in good state). I replaced the battery according the instruction but after turn on the server the warning message is still in the System Management.

I have read that the battery takes time to charge, but I replaced the battery two days ago (around 50 hours).

Also I updated the server with this SPP (http://h17007.www1.hp.com/us/en/enterprise/servers/products/service_pack/spp/index.aspx?version=2014.06.0) with the online mode (using the browser executing hpsum.bat).

The firmware of the Smart Array E200i is 1.86 (the latest).

What can I do at this point?
May be the battery adquired would be in a bad state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you purchased a bad battery.

But please see: [Smart Array P400 - Accelerator Replacement Battery Failure](https://serverfault.com/questions/426169/smart-array-p400-accelerator-replacement-battery-failure/426191#426191)

You could try a full power off of the system (removing power cables) and try again. But you've most likely acquired a bad battery.