# Unsupported Storage Connection Detected on HP DL380 Gen8

Tags: raid, hp, hp-proliant, sas, hp-smart-array

I'm hoping this is the right place to ask. I recently received a new HL DL380 Gen8 server, on which I want to install Server 2012 R2 via Intelligent Provisioning.

According to the specifications, there's no FBWC installed. On POST, the server reports the following error:

"HP Dynamic Smart Array B320i RAID Controller
1746-Drive Array – Unsupported Storage Connection Detected – SAS connection via expander is not supported on this controller model. Access to all storage has been disabled. Upgrade controller or detach the expander based storage connections."

Does the lack of FBWC have anything to do with that? Neither ACU or Intelligent Provisioning are able to see the harddrives, so I'm unable to create an array. The drives are original HP-drives (http://h30094.www3.hp.com/product/sku/10389317)

The server was installed by our supplier, when we received it here, so I'd assume it was installed correctly.

Any tips on how to proceed from here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The 12-slot model of this server has a SAS expander installed on the drive backplane. Gen8 ProLiant servers [require a healthy FBWC cache module](https://serverfault.com/a/528989/13325) installed in the RAID controller in order to interface with an expander backplane.

[image]

**Your supplier messed up.**

Despite this, you'd want the FBWC for [performance reasons](https://serverfault.com/questions/450242/what-is-the-memory-module-on-a-raid-card-needed-for/450253#450253).

My recommendation is to get a P420 controller in the server, because it sounds like it's a DL380e unit. You'll be happier long-term with the better controller. If not, just get some cache for the existing controller and ***shame your HP supplier*** :)

Comment: Thanks! I had a feeling that was the issue! I'll go shame the supplier :-)

Comment: Do you know the part-number for the FBWC, if I wanted to utilize the existing controller (B320i)? I assume it's 631922-B21?

Comment: Deal with your supplier on this... The [Quickspecs state 631922-B21](http://www8.hp.com/h20195/v2/GetDocument.aspx?docname=c04168333).

Comment: Thanks. I don't trust them that much after this :-)

Answer (score 0):

Well the B320i only supports 8 disks/disk slots - have you added an additional disk cage or put this card in one of the 25-slot models? also I didn't think you *could* get a B320i without at least 512MB of FBWC - have you removed it?

Comment: There are four disks installed, all in all - and it's the 12 slot model.

I haven't removed the FBWC. I actually thought that the controller came with FBWC as default.. but it seems it was never there.

Answer (score -2):

This issue is nothing but a Cache issue. Might be carbon on a Raid Cache. 
i had suffer from this issue and fortunately it got resolved after rubbing cache.