# NVRAM in a controller RAID

Tags: raid, hp, controller

I have one HP server Proliant ML 350 G5 with raid controller E200i.
Diagnostic system shows the message (after system crash and reboot):

Malformed NVRAM detected.
Device: HP Smart Array Controller, Slot 0
Property name: World Wide ID

I am confused about NVRAM: is it relate at memory RAM for BBWC, added as optional for better performance, or it is a memory internal controller RAID?

thank you,

Max

Comment: Please also see http://serverfault.com/questions/450242/what-is-the-memory-module-on-a-raid-card-needed-for and if possible, translate the message into english.

Comment: I correct the message from italian to english.

Answer (score 2):

NVRAM (non volatile RAM) on a RAID controller is the area where the system configuration of the controller is stored. The controller won't work without it. On most RAID controllers, this will mean the controller is dead, as the NVRAM can't be easily replaced.

This is in contrast to the cache RAM that is, at least in principle, non-essential (and that often can be replaced by putting another DIMM in).

---

I might be wrong in that, as it turns out that this could be the cache memory that is broken.

Comment: so that, I could replace the controller ...?

Comment: Replacing the controller is always on option :), but I am not too sure now what the real issue is, so I won't recommend anything. I originally thought the NVRAM is just a tiny config RAM (which would indeed be essential), but if it's the cache RAM that gets named like that, it might be non-essential in some circumstances (see Choppers post).

Answer (score 1):

That's exactly what it is, it's a battery-backed write-cache - the E200/i supports R0 and R1 without this but NEEDS it for R5.

Comment: Do they really call *battery backed* RAM non-volatile?

Comment: Actually the newer controllers don't use a BBU but caps with enough power to dump the cache contents to nvram on power loss.  No dead battery risks, no rush to bring a dead system up (The BBU keeps RAM alive for days; the NVRAM lives for years) and it's less hassle ... unless it goes sour.