# HP ProLiant ML350 G5 2.5 Sata slow write speed

Tags: sas, sata, write

im currently running Windows Server 2012 R2 with a HGST (Hitachi) z7k500-500 2.5 SATA drive.

I have a Smart Array E200i.

Read is about 140MB/S but write is only from 7-14MB/S.

I already updated the smart array firmware but same problem.

I checked the disk for bad sectors but everything ok.

The disk was completly new and is only 2 days old.

I dont have any comparsion (like crystaldiskmark) to 10k SAS drives but i remember that they're very very faster.

screenshot: http://prntscr.com/ex93ic

Answer (score 1):

Things to think about:

- SATA disks on a Smart Array E200i will downshift to 1.5Gbps link speeds instead of 3Gbps or 6Gbps.
- Do you have a write cache (BBWC)? Is the battery healthy? If not, [you're losing performance](https://serverfault.com/questions/450242/what-is-the-memory-module-on-a-raid-card-needed-for/450253#450253) because incoming writes would incur disk rotational latency.
- Do you only have *one* disk? Would more drives make sense for performance and data protection purposes?

Comment: In logs since 2007 the battery is low so the write cache is temporaly disabled. Do i lose lot of performance with write cache disabled?

Comment: Yes, you do. [That's your problem](https://serverfault.com/questions/450242/what-is-the-memory-module-on-a-raid-card-needed-for/450253#450253).